# Is there a way to create tables like nested lists? (image for reference)

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsp

In my app, an user can select some of his followers to see some of their followers.

I want the result of my function to appear like the image: 
[image: followers and follower's followers]
(please don't mind wrong spacing)

but I haven't been able to properly nest tables or to shift table rows left or right.

Here's the code I have used to generate the image:

```css
table {
  position: relative;
  left: 126px;
  margin-left: 16px;
  margin-top: 16px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
.avatar {
  width: 52px;
  height: 52px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #abc;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
tr {
  height: 70px;
  width: 732px;
}
td {
  height: 70px;
  margin: 0px;
}
p {
  margin-right: 16px;
  line-height: 70px;
}
.flldfll {
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-left: 91px;
}
```

```html
<div id="complist">
  <table class="fll">


    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="avatar"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>Nome Cognome</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>@nickname</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>ID</p>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </table>

  <table class="flldfll">


    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="avatar"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>Nome Cognome</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>@nickname</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>ID</p>
      </td>
    </tr>



  </table>

  <table class="fll">


    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="avatar"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>Nome Cognome</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>@nickname</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>ID</p>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </table>

  <table class="fll">


    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="avatar"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>Nome Cognome</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>@nickname</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>ID</p>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </table>



</div>
```

Here's the pseudocode of what I would like yo accomplish:

```
int count= 10; //numbers of followers to show
for(i<count, i++){
    generate YourFollowers <tr>s;
        if(YourFollowers.ID == FollowerPreviouslySelected.ID) {
            for(j<count, j++){
                generate FollowersFollowers <tr>s; //<tr>s shifted to right
            }
        }
}
```

Is there a proper way to reach my goal? (I'm working with jsp pages)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Are you sure you want to use table layout, or is that only way you're aware of doing it?

Comment: Hello guys, I updated my question with what I have tried! I am not sure I want to use table layout, I have tried with ulists before but I was not able to maintan a column layout for the same type of information. (for example all the names under the same column)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there's one "best practice" way of doing this, but this is how I would approach it:

First, just use an `<ul>` like normal. However, you can have table elements inside of the `<ul>`. For example:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <table class="ListTable">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Content
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </li>
    <li>
        <table>...</table>
        <ul>
            <!-- Do what was done in the first li here -->
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

So, as you can see, within each `<li>` you could have a self contained table, and style it as necessary with `.ListTable`. You could also, instead of using tables (which aren't very mobile friendly), you could use `<div>`'s that are given styling something like:

```
div.ListTableElement
{
    display: inline-table;
    ...
}
```

Possibly also adding in fixed/% based widths for all `.ListTableElement`.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would use nested un-ordered lists. Below is a basic example of how I would approach the layout you have provided.

```html
<ul>
    <li>
        <div>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50/?text=avatar"/>
            <span class="name">John Smith</span>
            <span class="handle">Handle</span>
            <span class="user-id">ID</span>
        </div>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <div>
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50/?text=avatar"/>
                    <span class="name">John Smith</span>
                    <span class="handle">Handle</span>
                    <span class="user-id">ID</span>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>                
                <div>
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50/?text=avatar"/>
                    <span class="name">John Smith</span>
                    <span class="handle">Handle</span>
                    <span class="user-id">ID</span>
                </div>                
            </li>
            <li>                
                <div>
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50/?text=avatar"/>
                    <span class="name">John Smith</span>
                    <span class="handle">Handle</span>
                    <span class="user-id">ID</span>
                </div>                
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50/?text=avatar"/>
            <span class="name">John Smith</span>
            <span class="handle">Handle</span>
            <span class="user-id">ID</span>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50/?text=avatar"/>
            <span class="name">John Smith</span>
            <span class="handle">Handle</span>
            <span class="user-id">ID</span>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

```css
ul {
    list-style: none;
}
img {
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 50%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-right: 15px;
}
span {
    display: inline-block;
}
li > div {
    margin: 15px 0;
}
.name,
.handle {
    width: 100px;
}
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jrp46cue/

Comment: thanks hungerstar, that's what I have tried to do at first. By the way I wasn't been able to maintant the same type of information under the same column. I hope you can understand what i mean :)

Comment: Unfortunately I do not know what you mean.